# Customize name of NetBeans 'dist/lib' folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to know if it is possible to auto-generate a folder structure for distribution in Netbeans?

```
Example:

dist/
    libraries/
              3rd party/
              custom/
    plugins/
    etc/
```

I noticed that I can change the name of the **'dist'** folder by changing the property **dist.dir=dist** to **dist.dir=bin** in the project.properties file.

Can I also do that for the dist/lib folder?

Comment: Just edit the netbeans/product.properties file, but bin/libraries isn't an appropriate repacement for dist/lib. The dist part won't be there on deployment.

Comment: The netbeans/product.properties file doesn't have any property for the lib folder. **Do you know a property (like dist.dir) that allows to specify a different name or location for the lib folder?**